# Flume agent reading from Kafka and storing data in parquet format

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-kafka, parquet, flume

I would like to configure a Flume agent which should read from a Kafka topic, and save the data in Parquet format. How should i do this? I couldn't find a solution for directly writing the data in the Parquet format

Answer (score 2):

Flume HDFS sink does not write in parquet by default because you cannot append rows to it. Best is to write avro files using Flume and trigger a MapReduce job or Impala when a file is completed to do an Avro to Parquet.

Comment: Yes ... and then the question becomes why do you need Flume at all: you can write a **Spark** or MR job that reads from Kafka and writes to Parquet directly.

Comment: can we write streaming data directly into hdfs as parquet format ? @mazaneicha

Comment: You could, but parquet is a non appendable file format, so write spark streaming batches to parquet end up being a file being rewritten everytime you append a new line. If you have lots of files being updated it can lead to performances issues